# Search for pattern in a file

Tags: powershell, csv

How do I search for an exact string in a file, which is separated with semicolons?

Like: `username;password;birthdate`

So that I can list the users who were born before 2000?

Comment: Since this looks like CSV, if you provide an example we can probably provide you a better solution then using e. g. the `Select-String` cmdlet.

Comment: you can use get-content and loop the file in every line. then use -match and build a [regex](https://regex101.com/) - but maybe you better use import-csv and do it in a foreach. and check the birthdate by $_.birthdate...

Comment: py504n;password;1997.12.27;

Comment: yeah a foreach might be good :D thanks for the idea

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Import-Csv` cmdlet and filter them using the `Where-Object` cmdlet:

```
Import-Csv 'your_csv_file' -Delimiter ';' | 
    Where {($_.birthdate -split '\.')[0] -le 2000}
```

Comment: Just to add the input CSV will either need headers that match the columns, or you will need to specify the headers for `Import-CSV` using `-Headers "username","password","birthdate"`